Nginx redirect url requests to local hosted service
I'm new to Nginx so please forgive me if this has been asked previously. I've been at my wits end debugging this for hours and couldn't find information related to my case.
I am running a remote Ubuntu server for a website project. I am using Nginx as the server. Accessing the website via the domain name http://mywebsite.com correctly serves the front end page. I am running a separate local program bound to localhost:3000 to handle API requests, which I want to redirect requests to, with the link as http://mywebsite.com/api/do_thing.
Accessing this endpoint with the base IP address and port works fine, but does not work with using the domain name. Postman returns a 405 Not Allowed response every time.
After some research, I have tried formatting my mywebsite.com "default" file as such:
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/mywebsite.com;
    index index.html;
    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api/do_thing {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/do_thing;
        proxy_redirect http://mywebsite.com/api/do_thing http://0.0.0.0:3000/do_thing;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_Proto $scheme;
    }
}

After reviewing the access logs, I'm finding that the POST requests sent to http://mywebsite.com/api/do_thing from my IP aren't even registering in Nginx. What am I doing wrong, and how does one enable such API request forwarding?

No, you DO NOT want to redirect (this means something very different in HTTP) you want to reroute or proxy the request. "but does not work with using the domain name" - using the port number of the application server? If so, then you really should fix this first before worrying about nginx.

Thank you for the response. I solved my problem and wanted to let any possible future readers know. My problem was not with my local program or Nginx, but I incorrectly figured my domain name through the service I was using. I set the domain name requests to be forwarded to the server’s IP, but I was actually supposed to create a DNS record with the IP. I did not need forwarding in this case.

Also I should clarify, I only temporarily opened up the particular port this local application was using for testing purposes. Wanted to make sure it was actually up and reachable by POST
